# Copy data from one table to another when column sizes are different

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables t1 (old) with 4 columns and t2 (new table) with 6 columns.

I want to copy the data from `t1` to `t2` with date and 'ÝES' as default values in T2 as these values are not available in T1.

- **T1** - 4 columns (c1, c2, c3, c4)
- **T2** - 6 columns (c1, c2, c3, c4, getdate(), 'ÝES') like I need

Please help me with this.

Comment: I tried with select * into T2 from T1 and insert into t2 from t1 etc . but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the desired result:

```
insert into T2 (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) select c1,c2,c3,c4,sysdate, 'ÝES' from T1;
```